# FormsAuthentication.Authenticate fails to authenticate

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership, forms-authentication

I currently have an odd problem with ASP.Net authentication. 
Consider the two following lines:

```
MembershipCreateStatus ct = new MembershipCreateStatus();
Membership.CreateUser("admin", "mypassword", "test@gmail.com", "1", "1", true,  out ct);
```

This does register my user in my database. I have verified this.
However, when I run this immediately after:

```
FormsAuthentication.Authenticate("admin", "mypassword");
```

The authentication fails. The weird thing is I know for a fact that the user does exist in the db, and that is further confirmed if i run

```
MembershipUserCollection uc =  Membership.FindUsersByName("admin");
```

and uc does hold my admin user withe all the proper info.
Any ideas or hints from anyone as to why Authenticate would return false?

Comment: Is the entire sequence w/i a single http request? You might try doing this over the course of two separate requests. How about creating "admin" one time, Session.Abandon(), reload the page and then see if you're able to authenticate.

Comment: Hrm nope. Not even if I try to authenticate on a separate page. The problem has to be coming from the password part right? I mean what else could go wrong if the user exists?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I learned something a little while ago - when looking up info on MSDN **always** read the remarks section. You'll be surprised that it usually contains the most vital info which, if not covered, can trap you for hours sometimes days. See that section for that method [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.authenticate.aspx). Then call [ValidateUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.validateuser.aspx) to authorze which is different from authenticate. Have a look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authentication#Authentication_vs._authorization).

Comment: Ahh thanks. That makes sense. It's easy to get lost in msdn and not read the remarks section in every page heh.

Comment: Many nights of sleep lost there to realize this recently which was actually from answering questions on this site. I had 2-3 questions that I answered in a row which were just from there so then I strated to look if that's the case at work & it's mostly that about 70% when there is a tricky situation - try it yourself and you'll be surprised. Then again 'Remarks' would be much more readable if it was in red font or even better call that section 'Important'. Such small thing but Microsoft will never change it because its possibly part of their obfuscation tactics to keep developers in the dark